# "ifelse" command in the "include"

Tags: php, include

where in error?

```
  <?
  if($_GET['data'])
  {
    print 'atmam';
include ('http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1');
  }
  else {
   print 'fail to download'; }
   ?>
```

Written on the screen error:

```
    Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=1) state=1 in                         http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1 on line 515

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1 on line 515
```

PS: http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1 = direct file download link

Can you help?
Best regards

Comment: The errors are on the included file.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are including, make sure its a PHP file.. its kind of dangerous to include a http url, anyway you can find your error simply in http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1 at line 515

Comment: I think you should use `file_get_contents` instead of include, because what your are trying to do is to actually include the file into your page

Comment: The file you have included is a binary file (as you can tell from the first error). I think what you actually want to do (although this is a stretch) is probably `readfile($url);`. Alternatively, @KristerAndersson suggestion of `file_get_contents();` may be what you want. Please explain exactly what you are trying to achieve so we can help you with the correct coding approach.

Comment: Thank you for answers! Automatically display the file download will request. Routing code was using previously, but the problems constituted. `file_get_contents` I can not run, write to the screen characters. How can I automatically download a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does something like what you want:

```
<?php

  if ($_GET['data']) {

    // Some headers that indicate a generic download
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment');

    // Try and read the file directly to the client
    if (!@readfile('http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1')) {
      // Try and clear the header and print a message. This may not work depending on the result of the readfile() attempt.
      @header('Content-Disposition:');
      print 'fail to download';
    }

    exit;

  }

?>
```

An alternative (and many would argue better) approach is this:

```
<?php

  if ($_GET['data']) {

    // Redirect the client to the actual location
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1');
    exit;

  }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! 
screen print: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/emre2010/public_html/0_alanlar/downloads/DWTEST.php:4) in /home/emre2010/public_html/0_alanlar/downloads/DWTEST.php on line 49 Rar!ϐs �t �,�d��:qpW�xx?3 SC4.png�p �L�MUU�r��e��B�n_D��|r�_ ...

Comment: Please edit your question with your entire script. You need to remove all calls to `echo`, `print` or anything else that produces output.

Comment: All the "echo and print" removed but same problem..
(Im sorry,intermediate level in English)

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides a function called file_exists for this purpose.  $_GET['data'] is for getting information out of the html element with name="data" attached to it.  If you do not have this in your document the script will NEVER run as its looking for something that doesn't exist.  Even if the element does exist, this is not a necessary nor recommended use of $_GET.

To find out more about what you're trying to do check this link, and look at my examples.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

To use it you simply do this:

```
    $filename = 'http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
         echo 'atmam';
         include ('$filename');
    }
    else
         echo 'Failed to download file';
```

I'm assuming you are going to use this for any files your site has to access, to save you time you can use it in a function.

```
 function testfile(filename)  {
       if (file_exists(filename)) {
         echo 'atmam';
         include ('filename');
      }
      else
         echo 'Failed to download file';
}
```

Call the function like this:

```
    $filename1 = 'http://downloads.website.com/download/3725f5eea93437e9de52f9b15854f5c1';
    $filename2 = 'something.txt';

    function testfile($filename1);
```

Using the function you can check as many file names as you want using variables for each file name.

Edit:  To solve the syntax error that is coming up, you must make sure the file being included has no errors.  Please post it here for us to look at.  Removing echos and prints will change nothing, in fact you want those in there in order to debug.  First try using the small bit of code I've put here, this is the correct method to check if a file exists, and if it does, do something.  Once you are using the correct code to check the file and include it, then you will be sure that once you fix any issues in the include file you are going to have the functionality you want.

Hope this helps you out!
-Sean

Comment: Thank you for interesting but only the "Failed to download file" write to. Does not implement the file download. my incompetence..